# Database operations in HTMLHelper, is that okay?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html-helper

**Hi,**

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 website and I need to build a image wall that takes a list of IDs and then build the imageWall based on this list.

The imagewall will be a partialView.

First thought was to place a list on the current ViewClass with IDs to the images that will be displayed but Im not sure this is a good solution, especially not if this imagewall was moved to another parentView.

So the question is. Can I make DB operations from within a HTML helper? What is best practice?

This partial view will probably be chaced.

Comment: Yes its possible, but no, you shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do it in the first place?

I think you should return a List from you Controller action and then iterate over it in your View, like:

```
foreach(var image in @Model.Images)
{
    // output some HTML code here using each image file path...
    <img src="@image.Path" />
}
```

You can use the [@Html.RenderAction](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/aspnet-mvc-2-render-action) in this case. You call it this way:

```
@Html.RenderAction("GetImages", "ImageWall");
```

Where ImageWall is is your new ImageWall `Controller` and GetImages is the name of your `Action`.

This will allow you to work with your ImageWall controller when inside another Controller's view.

Comment: My Controller action do already have a complexed ViewClass that is returned to the View. As I state, I was thinking of placing the list of images in this ViewClass but that means that If the partial view(imagewall) is moved to another View I will have to include this list on that ViewClass as well. If I would use the bag to transport tempdata to the view I would also have to do this int multiple actions that thats why I thought that HTMLHelper would be a good way. With that I will not need to care where I put this imagewall, it will handle itself.

Comment: You could create a separate `ImagewallController` and it's views. Then if you ever need to move the ImageWall from one place to another, you'd just call the partial view where you now need it.

Comment: So you mean that I should use two controllers and actions for displaying this page with the partial imageWall? How does that work? Could I state that when using this parial view it will run the correct action on the ImagewallController? Right now Im just using Render.Partial and sometimes I pass a bit of the Model to this partial view but it would be nace to avoid placing this data on the ModelView.

Comment: Nice, but will this not return a full View instead of a partial view?

Comment: No... it'll render only what you tell it to render (GetImages view is where you define what you want to render). It'll append `GetImages` result to the current view where you called it.